# How to use tileserver-gl with free maps?

Tags: openstreetmap, openmaptiles

I'd like to use tileserver-gl for hosting OSM map tiles. I don't want to use paid .mbtiles file from OpenMapTiles.com.

Is it possible to use tileserver-gl with some other (free) mbtiles file? How to set up that?

Comment: I guess you can generate your own .mbtiles using their styles which are free to use. Tiles can be generated with mapnik or with https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker

Comment: I tried tilemaker with the config.json and process.lua from `resources` directory. The .mbtiles file generated successfully but tilemaker still doesn't provide the same services (geojson, raster tiles... - only vector tilejson was available) as when I'm using the original OpenMapTiles file. Any instructions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've had good results with `mapbox/tippecanoe`, you can generate your own geojson, then convert to mbtiles. https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe